# How can we connect Documentum content management and Salesforce CRM Content?

Tags: salesforce, documentum

How can we connect Documentum content management and Salesforce CRM Content? Is there any quick reference available? Do I have to write custom connector?

Answer (score 0):

Contact www.perficient.com, they make a connector.  Or take a look at Mulesoft.  SFDC has APIs but I doubt you want to roll your own solution.

You CAN [use the dataloader to upload documents](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_content.htm&language=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

If you have licenses for Business Process Integrator you can create integration via webservices, direct sql commands and etc with graphical tool Process Builder (or xCP Designer).